# what does free or forced torque mean in robot arm dynamics?

Tags: robotic-arm, dynamics, torque

I'm trying to understand the dynamics (torque , velocity, etc )  of how a simple 2 DoF robotic arm rotates.
I am using the RoboAnalyzer simulator [1](http://www.roboanalyzer.com/) .

It has a Inverse Dynamics setting of "Free" or "Forced" Torque.
You select "Free" or "Forced".

What doe that mean ?
What gets changed if that setting is changed ?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* agribot, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the technical support team for a specific software package aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Try contacting the authors of the software.

Answer (score 1):

Free torque is a torque that is applied to a joint without any external load or resistance. This type of torque is used to model the behavior of a joint that is moving freely, such as an arm swinging back and forth with no external forces acting upon it. In a robot simulation, free torque may be used to test the limits of a joint's range of motion or to evaluate the performance of a control algorithm in the absence of external disturbances.

Forced torque, on the other hand, is a torque that is applied to a joint in response to an external load or disturbance. This type of torque is used to model the behavior of a joint that is interacting with its environment, such as a robot arm lifting a heavy object or pushing against an obstacle. In a robot simulation, forced torque may be used to test the ability of a robot to handle different types of loads or to evaluate the effectiveness of a control algorithm in the presence of external disturbances.